# How to change page on document ready in jQueryMobile

Tags: jquery-mobile, http-status-code-404, document-ready

I'm trying to change page on document ready

```
$.mobile.changePage('#loginPage');
```

but it throws a 404 error:

```
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://localhost/mBanka/v5/loginPage"
```

Comment: Try browsing http://localhost/mBanka/v5/loginPage directly from your browser. If it also throws a 404 error, then something might be wrong with your loginPage and not necessarily the jQueryMobile code.

Answer (score 0):

Look into jQM events http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0b1/#/demos/1.0b1/docs/api/events.html

```
$('div').live('pageshow',function(event, ui){
  alert('This page was just hidden: '+ ui.prevPage);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like an example of not reading the docs carefully. :)

You need to pass a jQuery object if referencing page in the same document. This should work.

```
$.mobile.changePage($('#loginPage'));
```

If not - put more info in your question